# Using AveragePooling2D instead of GlobalAveragePooling 2D to replace the Dense layers after an FCN for classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

Can I use a an AveragePooling2D layer with  the pool_size equal to the size of the feature map instead of a GlobalAveragePooling2D layer? the purpose of this is to replace a dense layer after an FCN. IS  GlobalAveragePooling2D a special case of AveragePooling2D??

Answer (score 2):

`GlobalAveragePooling2D` will downsample an input by taking the average value along the spatial dimensions and return a 1D output by default, unless you set `keepdims= True`. `AveragePooling2D` also downsamples an input but takes the average value over an input window defined by the `pool_size` parameter. So, it will return a 3D output:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.constant([[1., 2., 3.],
                 [4., 5., 6.],
                 [7., 8., 9.]])

x = tf.reshape(x, [1, 3, 3, 1]) # Add batch dimension

avg_pool_2d = tf.keras.layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),
   strides=(1, 1), padding='valid')
avg_global_2d = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()
print(avg_pool_2d(x).shape)
print(avg_global_2d(x).shape)
```

```
(1, 2, 2, 1)
(1, 1)
```

You will probably have to flatten your output from the `AveragePooling2D` layer if you want to feed it to a `Dense` layer afterwards:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.constant([[1., 2., 3.],
                 [4., 5., 6.],
                 [7., 8., 9.]])

x = tf.reshape(x, [1, 3, 3, 1]) # Add batch dimension

avg_pool_2d = tf.keras.layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),
   strides=(1, 1), padding='valid')
avg_global_2d = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()
print(tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(avg_pool_2d(x)).shape)
print(avg_global_2d(x).shape)
```

```
(1, 4)
(1, 1)
```

If that is not the case you can just leave it as it is.

Update: `GlobalAveragePooling2D` and `AveragePooling2D` can sometimes behave similarly if you adjust the `strides` and `pool_size` parameters accordingly:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.constant([[1., 2., 3.],
                 [4., 5., 6.],
                 [7., 8., 9.]])

x = tf.reshape(x, [1, 3, 3, 1]) # Add batch dimension

avg_pool_2d = tf.keras.layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),
   strides=(3, 3), padding='valid')
avg_global_2d = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()

print(avg_pool_2d(x))
print(avg_global_2d(x))
```

```
tf.Tensor([[[[3.]]]], shape=(1, 1, 1, 1), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([[5.]], shape=(1, 1), dtype=float32)
```

Or

```
avg_pool_2d = tf.keras.layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3),
   strides=(2, 2), padding='valid')
avg_global_2d = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()
```

```
tf.Tensor([[[[5.]]]], shape=(1, 1, 1, 1), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([[5.]], shape=(1, 1), dtype=float32)
```

Comment: 'x =  Input(shape=(128,128,3))'         after many more FCN layers I get to :                                                                                 'a = Conv2D(200 ,(1,1), padding = 'same' ,
 activation='softmax', data_format = 'channels_last')(output_of_the_layer_before)'       is the last convolutional layer then I do                                                                                               'b  =   Lambda(lambda x: squeeze(x, axis=2))(AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(1, 128))(a)

Comment: This works perfectly fine for the specific task I have, which made me wonder that using GlobalaveragePooling2D might not be the only option available for replacing dense layers... also with GlobalAveragePooling2D you have the option of 'keepdims= True' or 'keepdims= False' , can't share my code, I hope this made sense to you

Comment: Yes, it made sense to me.. but what exactly is your question now or what are you not understanding?

Comment: How by using the AveragePooling2D layer like described above leads to almost the same classification results as GlobalAveragePooling2D! Usually in literature I have almost always seen GlobalAveragePooling2D as a replacement for Dense layers in FCN but never saw AveragePooling2D being used instead of a Dense layer

Comment: Updated answer but could not reproduce the code you added in the comments.. please update your question with the relevant code,  the result, and your question.

Comment: Global average pooling is nothing special. You can use average pooling with filter size equal to the input size and valid padding, then it's exactly the same. You could even use functions like `tf.reduce_mean`. The reason nobody does this is that it's just way easier to use global pooling directly...

Comment: @xdurch0 , makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answer above, global average pooling can be used for taking variable size images as inputs. If the input shape before global pooling is `(N,H,W,C)` then output will be `(N,1,1,C)` for keras when `keepdims=True`. This makes the output of images with different `(H,W)` produce similar shape outputs.

##### References:

- https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/388859/is-it-possible-to-give-variable-sized-images-as-input-to-a-convolutional-neural